# Reset Bootstrap button to the normal styles after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Buttons in Bootstrap would be active after clicking and remain in active status.
I applied `removeClass();` to remove the `'btn-active'` which would be added after clicking. However it does not work for me.

```js
function func(e){
  $(e.currentTarget).removeClass("btn-active");
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container m-5">
  <input type="button" value="correct" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="func(event)">
</div>
```

Comment: When does it become active?

Comment: I think it happens before calling onclick function.

Comment: Buttons does not get `btn-active` unsell you tell it to, and your code removes it just fine if it has the class. Somewhere in your code you must have something like `.addClass("btn-active")`

Comment: So how can I reset back the button to its former style before clicked?

Comment: @AliR We can't tell you since we cant see your code,  you have to look at your code and figure out when btn-active is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$(e.currentTarget).removeClass("btn-active");
```

you can simply [trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) in order to remove the focus effect.

```js
function func(e){
  $(e.currentTarget).trigger("blur");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" value="correct" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="func(event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle the active state of the button, I suggest you grab the `target` of the event and use an appropriate Boostrap class.

```js
function toggleActive(e) {
  $(e.target).toggleClass('active');
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary active"
  onclick="toggleActive(event)"
  value="correct">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS

```
.btn:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #007bff;
}
```

This will remove the style after the button click. Check the snippet

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
    .btn:focus {
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        background: #007bff;
    }
</style>

<input type="button" value="correct" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container m-5">
        <input type="button" value="correct" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$(this).blur();">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You just need to call `blur` method on `this` object when user click the button, which removes focus from the button as it get clicked.